# Use hardware in a aws cloud infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hello I created a complete application and It is hosted in AWS, right now I have to use a device with my application and It should be connected to the server, the problem is that the server is an amazon ec2 instance. The question is how can I solve this problem?, I thought to connect my vpc with my company vpn and here use a dedicated server and connect my device there, but I'm not sure if there is a better solution to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the nature of the "device?"

Comment: It's a key generator to activate devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the device in the same vpc (via vpn) is the right solution for what you are trying to do if you want to move forward with AWS. You will need a physical server somewhere you can connect the hardware too.

Minor suggestion: don't connect the whole company vpn to the vpc. Create a separate one only for your application (at least initially).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, if you need custom hardware attached to the server, is to colocate a physical server in a data center near you that you can get your hands on. AWS does not seem like the right solution in this case.